# Hilbert scheme of divisors in smooth projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $L$ be a line bundle with $H^0(X,L)\neq 0$. Let $D\in |L|$ and $p(t)$ be the Hilbert polynomial of $D$. Assume that any effective divisor $D'\subset X$ with the Hilbert polynomial $p(t)$ is in the linear series $D'\in |L|$.

Question: Is it always true that $\mathrm{Hilb}^{p(t)}_X\cong \mathbb{P}H^0(X,L)$?

If $X$ is a projective space, the result is known. I'm wondering if anyone has ever proven a generalization of this result. For example, is there any reference when $X$ a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{\dim X+1}$ with $\dim X\geq 2?$

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  That is not true.  Let $X$ be a quartic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ that contains a unique line $D$.  It is true for smooth hypersurfaces of dimension $\geq 3$ by the Grothendieck -- Lefschetz theorem on Picard groups.

Comment: Sorry for the late contribution, but I do not understand your comment. The line $D$ on $X$ satisfies $D^2=-2$, hence $H^0(D, \, N_{D/X})=0$ and so the Hilbert scheme is smooth of dimension $0$ (at least, at $[D]$). So, it seems to me that the component containing $D$ coincides with  $\mathbb{P}H^0(X, \, D)$. Are there other components? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Although the Hilbert scheme of $X$ actually depends on the choice of an ample line bundle on $X$, here we leave this ambiguous.

I think it would be true.

Write $\mathbb{P}:= \mathbb{P}H^0(X,L) := \mathrm{Proj}_k(\mathrm{Sym}(H^0(X,L)^*))$, where $\mathrm{Sym}$ is the symmetric algebra.
Then the closed points of $\mathbb{P}$ corresponds bijectively the set of effective divisors of $X$ which is linealy equivalent linearly to $D$.

Write $\mathcal{D}\subset X\times \mathbb{P}$ for the ``universal'' effective divisor, i.e., the closed subscheme such that for any effective divisor $D\subset X$, the following diagram (outer square) is cartesian:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D @>{\subset}>> X @>>> \mathrm{Spec}(k) \\
@VVV @VVV @VV{[D]}V \\
\mathcal{D} @>{\subset}>> X\times \mathbb{P} @>>> \mathbb{P},
\end{CD}
$$
where the morphism $[D]:\mathrm{Spec}(k)\to \mathbb{P}$ is determined by the effective divisor $D\subset X$.
Since all fibers of $\mathcal{D}\to \mathbb{P}$ have same Hilbert polynomial, we obtain a morphism of $k$-schemes.
$$
\psi: \mathbb{P}H^0(X,L) = \mathbb{P} \to \mathrm{Hilb}_X^{p(t)}.
$$
Moreover, since the fibers of $\mathcal{D} \to \mathbb{P}$ determine distinct closed subschemes of (X) each other, for any closed point $x\in \mathrm{Hilb}_X^{p(t)}$, the scheme-theoretic fiber $\psi^{-1}(x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}(k(x))$ (if $\psi^{-1}(x)\neq\emptyset$).
In particular, $\psi$ is quasi-finite.
Since $\mathbb{P}$ is projective, $\psi$ is finite.
Since each scheme-theoretic fiber of $\psi$ is trivial (or empty), $\psi^{\#}: \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Hilb}} \to \psi_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}$ is surjective.
Thus $\psi$ is a closed immersion.

Let $D'\subset X$ be a closed subscheme whose Hilbert polynomial is $p(t)$.
Then, since $\mathrm{dim}(D') = \mathrm{deg}(p(t)) = \mathrm{dim}(D)$, $D'$ is an effective divisor.
Hence, by our assumption, the point $[D']\in \mathrm{Hilb}_X^{p(t)}$ determined by the closed subscheme $D'\subset X$ contained in the image of $\psi$, i.e., $\psi$ is surjective.
Since $\psi$ is a closed immersion, $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: The last paragraph of your argument is incomplete (the sentence starting with "Hence" is not explained). Note also that a subscheme $D'$ may have some irreducible (or embedded) components of dimension less than $\dim(X) - 1$, so it need not be a divisor.